# state is not updating in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Actually it is not updating everywhere i suppose it to update.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";

import { TextField } from "react-native-material-textfield";

import Colors from "../constants/Colors";

const welcomescreen = (props) => {
  let [length, setLength] = useState();
  let [breadth, setBreadth] = useState();
  let [height, setHeight] = useState();
  let [volume, setVolume] = useState();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const lengthInputHandler = (l) => {
    setLength(l);
  };
  const breadthInputHandler = (br) => {
    setBreadth(br);
  };
  const HeightInputHandler = (h) => {
    setHeight(h);
  };

  let lengthIntPart,
    breadthIntPart,
    heightIntPart,
    lengthinInches,
    breadthinInches,
    heightinInches,
    res;

  const volumeCalc = () => {
    lengthIntPart = Math.floor(parseFloat(length));
    lengthinInches =
      (lengthIntPart + (parseFloat(length) - lengthIntPart) / 1.2) * 12;

    breadthIntPart = Math.floor(parseFloat(breadth));
    breadthinInches =
      (breadthIntPart + (parseFloat(breadth) - breadthIntPart) / 1.2) * 12;

    heightIntPart = Math.floor(parseFloat(height));
    heightinInches =
      (heightIntPart + (parseFloat(height) - heightIntPart) / 1.2) * 12;

    res = lengthinInches * breadthinInches * heightinInches;

    return res;
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.screen}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />

      <View style={styles.form}>
        <TextField
          label="Length"
          onChangeText={lengthInputHandler}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          textAlignVertical="center"
        />
        <TextField
          label="Breadth"
          onChangeText={breadthInputHandler}
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        <TextField
          label="Height"
          onChangeText={HeightInputHandler}
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
      </View>

      <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.calcBtn}
          onPress={() => {
            setVolume(volumeCalc());
            setLoading(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
              if (volume !== undefined) {
                props.navigation.navigate({
                  name: "resultscreen",
                  params: {
                    volume: volume,
                  },
                });
              }
              setLoading(false);
              console.log(volume);
            }, 3000);
          }}
          disabled={!!!length && !!!breadth && !!!height}
        >
          {!loading ? (
            <Text style={styles.text}>Calculate</Text>
          ) : (
            <ActivityIndicator size="small" color={Colors.white} />
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width: "90%" }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
          <Text>Volume :</Text> 
          <Text>{volume} cubic inches </Text> //line 14
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
          <Text>Volume:</Text>
          <Text>{volume / 1728} Cb. Feet</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
          <Text>Weight:</Text>
          <Text>{volume / 1728 / 25} Metric tonne</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};


export default welcomescreen;
```

`lines numbers are mentioned in comments of the code`

idk why that is happening but at line 149, towards the end of the code, it works fine but at line 89 onwards in the `onPress` method ,it does not change the state even there , and it passes the initialstate itself which is not defined , i tried initializing it with values like 0 and null and it still console.logged 0 and null respectively , so i put in a check for undefined so that so that it does not go to the next page if there is no real value

`the next screen aka resultscreen`

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const ResultScreen = (props) => {
  const volume = props.route.params.volume;
  console.log(volume);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{volume}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ResultScreen;
```

`again in the next screen if i let it go even if it is undefined, it console.logs undefined, which is quite obvious and dumb of me to put it here , but that is it'

`i have no idea why this is happening`

`NOTE : But if i press the button twice, it updates the state on the second click , its strange that is happening`

Comment: you put console.log after return in volumeCalc function

Comment: that was a mistake please ignore that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to save the volume in the state? You can navigate directly in the onPress action:

```
onPress={() => {
   let calculatedVolume = volumeCalc();
   props.navigation.navigate({
      name: "resultscreen",
      params: {
         volume: calculatedVolume,
      },
   });
}
```

Another approch is to calculate the volume and use it to set the state and for your navigation:

```
onPress={() => {
   let calculatedVolume = volumeCalc();
   setVolume(calculatedVolume);
   props.navigation.navigate({
      name: "resultscreen",
      params: {
         volume: calculatedVolume,
      },
   });
}
```

Comment: i'll try it but suppose that i need it ? why doesn't my code work ?

Comment: Your approach is not right. You shouldn't set the state and set a timer to do something later depending that the state must have changed. I can't see anywhere that you are using the volume except in your onPress function. You can just calculate it and use it.

Comment: I added alternative approach. When you use setVolume you can't expect to get the calculated value instantly, it is asynchronous method. If you calculate it and then use it to set the state and to navigate you will have the value and it won't be undefined.

Comment: Did it work? If no are there any problems, if yes can you accept the answer?

Comment: i understood your approach but if we make volumeCalc() an async function , can we do it my way , also i tried it did not work . can it tho?

Comment: it did work. `thank you` but can look at my comment above this one

Comment: Well it is not a function that does heavy operations - you are just calculating a value. That is a fast operation. If you make it async you will need to wait for it to finish and then navigate to the other screen. So that means you don't get any advantage of it being async. You should use async for time consuming operations like http requests.

Comment: Why is that? You are navigating to the other screen and already have the volume value. Is it undefined or what?

Comment: yes it is logging undefined from the log statement in the onpress

Comment: console.log(volume) will print undefined because the state is not yet updated. When setVolume is called it will update the volume variable but the change will be  visible on the next render. In the onPress you can log the calculatedVolume variable and see that it is with the right value. That's why we use it to navigate to the new screen and not the volume variable.